# Runtime exception with composer update and KnpPaginatorBundle

Tags: symfony, composer-php

When I run composer update I get this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Updating knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (dev-master 5386aa8 => 2.4.0)



  [RuntimeException]                                             
  Failed to execute git status --porcelain --untracked-files=no  

  fatal: bad object HEAD                                         




update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [packages1] ... [packagesN]
```

And I've not idea how to solve it. Can I update KnpPaginatorBundle by another way?

What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stuff breaks in the vendor directory, you can always delete it completely and let Composer create it again.

It seems like you are updating to a new released version, so if Composer still complains about that repository being broken, try to download a ZIP of that software:

```
composer update --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the entire vendor directory and I executed:

```
composer install
```

and it worked at the fifth time. Yes, it's magic stuff...